# HTML plugin for Claws-Mail 3.16?

Tags: html, plugin

I recently upgraded my Claws-Mail software to 3.16 (64-bit). I now find that it no longer has an HTML plugin (Fancy, Dillo, etc). Does anyone know of a plugin to display the HTML in email in Claws-Mail?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the plugins? Because the latest version of Dillo is released on 22 December 2018, 3.17.3.

Comment: Thanks! But the copy of Claws-Mail I have doesn't include it. I am using Ubuntu 18.04. All I have is the browser as a separate download. Know where I can download it w/o downloading the whole software?

Comment: Apparently the plugins listed in official Claws-mail site are already included with the installer. So maybe you can try to re-install Claws-Mail. I found in the ubuntu packages the dillo plugin https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=+claws-mail-dillo-viewer&searchon=names but I'm not sure what is your distro. You can try to download the tar file and extract the plugin: https://www.claws-mail.org/download.php?file=releases/claws-mail-3.16.0.tar.gz

Comment: Thanks. The download is for Claws-Mail v3.17.2-1 and I have v16 - the latest for Ubuntu 18.04. Would it be a problem if I upgraded to Claws-Mail with vClaws-Mail v3.17.2-1? UI just don't want to mess-up my new system installation.

Comment: According to a statement by Andrej Kacian, a developer at Claws Mail, They're not the ones who removed the plugin: "We did not remove the HTML plugin (called Fancy) from Claws Mail, it's just that many Linux distributions started removing the HTML library (webkitgtk) that this plugin uses, and therefore are not including this plugin".

Comment: Any news concerning this issue?

Comment: On the Claws-Mail mailing list, I was told that there was nothing yet. I am going to find out what Ubuntu is doing about it since they would have been the one who pulled it from the 18.04 package itself (according to the mailing list).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get claws mail 3.17 to display html on ubuntu 18.04.

You would first need the dillo browser to help render the html:

```
sudo apt install dillo
```

If you have an older version of claws, it must be uninstalled (the version in the ubuntu 18.04 repo was 3.16):

```
sudo apt remove claws-mail
```

***your config and mail is preserved***

download the latest edition of the claws mail and the html plugin from here:

[claws-mail 3.17](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/claws-mail)

[dillo viewer](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/claws-mail-dillo-viewer)

then install them:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

after installation load the html plugin:
Claws mail > configuration > plugins > load > Select "dillo.so"

after this you should be able to view html email. Opening images is disabled. to enable it go to Claws mail > configuration > preferences > plugins > dillo > and check "load remote links in mail"

if email is still being shown in plain text choose the email button on the right side of the mail email window

Comment: I have installed the Dillo plugin. After removing CM 16 I tried to load CM 17 but got the error that it needed libetpan20 >1.9.2. I only have 1.8.0.1 available through the Synaptic Pkg Manager. A search shows nothing. How did you get it?

Comment: Is there anything to do, for safe html viewing, when on Ubuntu 18.04? The deb packages suggested are for 19.04...